# Getting 502 on Contentful request when deploying dockerized nextjs app

Tags: docker, next.js, contentful, contentful-api

I'm trying to deploy a dockerized nextjs application but since I added Contentful to my app, the deployment fails on it's request.
Error: `ApolloError: Response not successful: Received status code 502`

[slug].tsx

```
import {
  GetStaticPathsContext,
  GetStaticPropsResult,
  InferGetStaticPropsType,
} from 'next';
import { useContentfulLiveUpdates } from '@contentful/live-preview/react';
import { useTranslation } from 'next-i18next';

import { client, previewClient } from 'contentful/client';
import { BlogPostPage } from 'pages/Blog';
import { getServerSideTranslations } from 'utils';

function Page(props: InferGetStaticPropsType<typeof getStaticProps>) {
  const { t } = useTranslation();

  const blogPost = useContentfulLiveUpdates(props.blogPost);
  const relatedPosts = blogPost?.relatedBlogPostsCollection?.items;

  if (!blogPost || !relatedPosts) return null;

  return <BlogPostPage blogPost={blogPost} relatedPosts={relatedPosts} />;
}

const revalidateDuration = 5;

export async function getStaticProps({
  params,
  locale,
  draftMode: preview,
}: any): Promise<GetStaticPropsResult<any>> {
  if (!params?.slug || !locale) {
    return {
      notFound: true,
      revalidate: revalidateDuration,
    };
  }

  const gqlClient = preview ? previewClient : client;

  try {
    const [blogPageData, landingPageData] = await Promise.all([
      gqlClient.pageBlogPost({ slug: params.slug.toString(), locale, preview }),
      gqlClient.pageLanding({ locale, preview }),
    ]);

    const blogPost = blogPageData.pageBlogPostCollection?.items[0];
    const landingPage = landingPageData.pageLandingCollection?.items[0];

    const isFeatured = landingPage?.featuredBlogPost?.slug === blogPost?.slug;

    if (!blogPost) {
      return {
        notFound: true,
        revalidate: revalidateDuration,
      };
    }

    return {
      revalidate: revalidateDuration,
      props: {
        ...(await getServerSideTranslations(locale)),
        blogPost,
        isFeatured,
      },
    };
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('e', e);
    return {
      notFound: true,
      revalidate: revalidateDuration,
    };
  }
}

export async function getStaticPaths({
  locales,
}: GetStaticPathsContext): Promise<any> {
  const dataPerLocale = locales
    ? await Promise.all(
        locales.map((locale) =>
          client.pageBlogPostCollection({ locale, limit: 100 }),
        ),
      )
    : [];

  const paths = dataPerLocale
    .flatMap((data, index) =>
      data.pageBlogPostCollection?.items.map((blogPost) =>
        blogPost?.slug
          ? {
              params: {
                slug: blogPost.slug,
              },
              locale: locales?.[index],
            }
          : undefined,
      ),
    )
    .filter(Boolean);

  return {
    paths,
    fallback: 'blocking',
  };
}

export default Page;
```

Dockerfile

```
##########
# Development
##########

FROM node:16-alpine AS deps

RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm ci

USER node

##########
# Build
##########

FROM node:16-alpine AS builder

WORKDIR /app

COPY --chown=node:node --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules

COPY . .
COPY .env.prod ./.env

ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1

RUN npm run build

# remove dev dependencies
RUN npm prune --production

USER node

##########
# Production
##########

FROM node:16-alpine AS runner

WORKDIR /app

USER node

ENV NODE_ENV production

COPY --chown=node:node next.config.js ./
COPY --chown=node:node .env.prod ./.env
COPY --chown=node:node --from=builder /app/public ./public

COPY --from=builder --chown=node:node /app/.next/standalone ./
COPY --from=builder --chown=node:node /app/.next/static ./.next/static

ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1

CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

Compose

```
version: '3'

services:
  website:
    build:
      context: ./website
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile.prod
    ports:
      - ${LOCAL_IP}:${WEBSITE_PORT}:3000
    env_file:
      - ./website/.env.prod
    dns:
      - 8.8.8.8
      - 4.2.2.4
      - 1.1.1.1
```

What I have tried:

- I have tried adding dns to config compose file
- Checking that all env variables are present
- The Contentful server is accessible in the container